# time array only one loop

Tags: javascript, time

I'm trying to get an array containing `hour:minutes` using only one loop.  so at the end I can get something close to: `[0:00, 0:01... 23:58, 23:59]` I know I can do it using two for loops such as:

```
for (var i=0;i<24;i++) {
    for (var j=0;j<60;j++) {
        // push i and j accordingly
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use two loops? I don't think there will be any speed gains.

Comment: @shef, I can't explain it, but http://jsperf.com/two-loops shows a good increase in perfomance on google chrome 13 at least

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my go:

```
var times = [];
for (var i=0;i<60*24;i++) {
    times.push(((i/60)|0) + ':' + i%60 );
}
console.log(times)
```

`(i/60)|0` is a stupid way to do `Math.floor` now that I'm looking at it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you run across the user IAbstract before?

Comment: @Michael, no I have not. Now I feel less creative :(